# i want support for 2 url patterns in my web project using spring mvc 3+jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

getting 406 not acceptable error when i specify two url patterns in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.view</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

below is my server call code

```
function showAll(){
        console.log('inside all');
        $.ajax({     
            url:'/SaveImages/ShowUser.view',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (resp) {
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log('Error: '+e);
            }  
        });
```

below is my controller code :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ShowUser.view", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User showUsers(ModelMap model) throws SQLException, IOException{
        ResultSet rst=null;
        User user=new User();
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement pst=null;
        try{

         conn=getConnection();
         pst=conn.prepareStatement("select user_name,image_filename,image from save_image where pid=?");
        pst.setInt(1, 2);

        String name=null;
         String fileName=null;
         CommonsMultipartFile ip=null;
         rst=pst.executeQuery();
        BufferedInputStream input=null;

        rst.next();

               name = rst.getString(1);
              fileName = rst.getString(2);

              String filePath="xyz";              

        user.setName(name);
        user.setEducation(ip);
        user.setFilePath(filePath);
            conn.close();           

    }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            rst.close();
            pst.close();
            conn.close();
            //out.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

i want to pass a model object in response.please help i am struggling for this since last 3 days.if i use .htm in ajax url i m not getting anything in response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try specifying response dataType in ajax syntax.**

```
dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
```

The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. 
//from jQuery.ajax() API doc

Comment: thanx for your reply.... now its working i specified dataType as 'json' and added jackson jar